# Error "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named seaborn", but the package seaborn is up to date

Tags: python, anaconda, seaborn, jupyter-lab

I'm running a simple code to draw a graph:

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.set(style="darkgrid")

# Load an example dataset with long-form data
fmri = sns.load_dataset("fmri")

# Plot the responses for different events and regions
sns.lineplot(x="timepoint", y="signal",
             hue="region", style="event",
             data=fmri)
```

and then I got the error message

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-b0fb62af2e98> in <module>
----> 1 import seaborn as sns
      2 sns.set(style="darkgrid")
      3 
      4 # Load an example dataset with long-form data
      5 fmri = sns.load_dataset("fmri")

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'seaborn'
```

Here is the screenshot from my JupyterLab:

[image]

It's weir to me because I use Anaconda and the package `seaborn` is up to date.

[image]

Could you please inform me how to fix this code? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just figured that I have two python distributions in my system, one from Anaconda (for which the package `seaborn` is already installed). The other one does not have the package `seaborn`. I open the JupyterLab from the latter one. This is where the problem arises.